# why could a check if (document.addEventListener) returns false

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

On what basis does a check `if (document.addEventListener)` return `false`? Is there a way we can change this?

Comment: If you are using Internet Explorer it will return false because it has its own method.

Answer (score 9):

`if (document.addEventListener)` evaluates to `false` if there's no `addEventListener` method in `document`. This check is usually done to see if you can use this method to attach event to DOM element (works in most browsers except IE).

*is there a way we can change this ?*
This question I don't completely understand. Probably, you want something like `document.attachEvent('onload', callback);` for IE. You can't really add `addEventListener` method to document (well, maybe you can, but it wouldn't make sense).

[Docs for addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener)

Comment: i mean is there anything i can do to add this method to the document ?

Comment: @Miroo No, but you can use IE-specific way to handle events. (like 'onload' in my example)

Comment: and it works with me on IE9 but on a different application under framework 4

Comment: unfortnally :S i am adding a new feature for IE9 which enable buttons in the thumbBar to do some JS functions so i have to attach that event 'msthumbnailclick'

Comment: @Miroo And none of two provided here ways to attach handlers work?

Answer (score 5):

If this code snippet returns `false`, this means that the `addEventListener` method property is not support by the browser. This is the [case for Internet Explorer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener#Internet_Explorer), where `attachEvent` is used instead:

```
if (document.addEventListener){  
  document.addEventListener(...);
} else if (document.attachEvent){  
  document.attachEvent(...);  
}
```

Comment: I am trying to use this to add a thumbBarButtons on IE9 and i tried the attachevent and it didn't work :S and all the code samples didn't mention that we can use it to attach the 'msthumbnailclick' event

Comment: IE9 supports addEventListener

Answer (score 2):

It returns a false value (although not actually `false`) if it isn't defined.

This is a standard [feature (AKA object) detection](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/support.html) test.

You could change it by implementing your own version. More usually you'll use this in a wrapper function with the `} else {` having IE specific handling.